# Как простую фукнцию всунут в представление класса?

Tags: python, django, классы

Я новичек в джанго, столкнулся в такой проблемой. Раньше я использовал во вьюшках только функции, но сейчас столкнулся  с представлениями класса. Мне нужно в класс exрenselistviеw разрешить поиск по дате(от и до). Я реализовал бы это отдельной функцией, но можете объяснить, чем будет отличаться эта функция внутри класса?
[image]

Comment: Код в вопросе должен быть в воспроизводимом (текстовом) виде.

Answer (score 1):

Да особо отличаться не будет

```
def do_something(self, <тут аргументы>):
 ""Тут логика, как у обычной функции"""
     return something # либо возвращаем что-то либо нет, опять же поведение как у функции
```

Вы определите метод, указываете в нём обязательное ключевое слово self, а дальше крутите как обычной функцией. Вероятно вам лучше сперва почитать про ООП, а потом уже пытаться расширять поведении классов.

Comment: В качестве request будет использоваться self, я правильно понял?

Comment: нет, вместе. без кода конечно не понять. но опять же вместо того, что бы гадать, ознакомьтесь с ООП в питоне.